# Работа отдельного потока с Jsoup. Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, парсер, jsoup

Был создан класс `Parser`,использующий Jsoup, который объединял в себе методы для парсинга значений с сайта. В обычной консоли все его методы работали прекрасно. Затем я перенёс этот класс в Android Studio для дальнейшего использования в приложении. Но в главном потоке нельзя взаимодействовать с интернетом поэтому я вынужден был перенести все использование `Parser` в новый поток:

```
class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        title = Parser.getRandomStory("title");
        content = Parser.getRandomStory("story");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        title_story.setText(title);
        content_story.setText(content);
    }
}
```

**upd**
Код метода:

```
public static String getRandomStory(String value){
    String link = "https://pastach.ru/p/random";
    String title = "Title: ";
    String story = "Story: ";
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
        Element title_text = doc.getElementsByClass("header-title").get(0);
        title += title_text.text();
        Element story_text = doc.getElementsByClass("paste-content").get(0);
        story += story_text.text();
        //System.out.println(title);
        //System.out.println(story);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return ("CONNECTION HAS BEEN LOST");
    }
    if(value.equals("story")){
        return story;
    }else{
        return title;
    }
}
```

**upd2:**
логи:

> 07-22 20:38:01.768 24422-24422/com.example.len.coolstorybro
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.len.coolstorybro, PID: 24422
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a
>   null object reference
>           at com.example.len.coolstorybro.RandomStoryFragment$ProgressTask.onPostExecute(RandomStoryFragment.java:54)
>           at com.example.len.coolstorybro.RandomStoryFragment$ProgressTask.onPostExecute(RandomStoryFragment.java:43)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5927)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:958)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:819)

Но по каким то причинам переменный `title` и `content` всегда равны `null`.
Что я делаю не так и как мне это исправить?

Comment: Сеть есть. Разрешение в манифесте указано. Код метода сейчас предоставлю

Comment: @woesss добавил в Upd

Comment: @woesss В режиме отладки я увидел что они равны null. Это вызывает NullPointerException. Но я раскомментировал System.out.println и в консоль значения опять таки попали

Comment: Если `onPostExecute` - это единственное место где Вы их используете - то `NullPointerException` это не может вызывать. Скорее всего Вы не инициализировали переменные `title_story / content_story` до запуска таска. **P.S.** Всегда прикладывайте стектрейс ошибки к вопросу, если таковая имеется.

Comment: @woesss title_story и content_story я иницилизировал (findViewById и т.д). Ошибки из логов прикрепил в upd2

Comment: Но логи говорят, что именно в них проблема - сверяйте `id` в коде и xml. Или показывайте код и разметку активности. `findViewById` - надеюсь в `onCreate` после `setContentView` применили?

Comment: @woess все таки вы были правы. У меня были проблемы с иницилизацией Textview. Все исправил и все работает, спасибо